# KeyTip not working in Microsoft Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

The 'KeyTip' is not working properly using the RibbonControlsLibrary (3.5.41019.1). I create a simple RibbonWindow:

1. Add a couple of tabs
2. Add some controls like a button
3. Set properties such as labels and headers
4. Set the *KeyTip* properties on the tabs

I test the KeyTip in *desgin mode (VS2010)* and everything works as expected. But when I build the project as a windows application the following occur:

- **ALT+KeyTip** only shows the keytips, no focus is changing. The expected behaviour would be a change of tab...

I tried to create a clean WpfRibbonProject and did the same thing and then it works for some reason. The none working project is a mixture of *Forms* and *WPF* and a form is displayed before the WPF window. Could this be the problem? I cannon see why this would be a problem?

Source code:

```
        <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                          Header="Home" KeyTip="H">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                                Header="Group1">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="Hej" KeyTip="T" />                    
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>

        </ribbon:RibbonTab>

        <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="Tab1">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Min grupp">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="Test" />
                <ribbon:RibbonSplitButton Label="Testen">
                    <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Jaha" />
                </ribbon:RibbonSplitButton>
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
        </ribbon:RibbonTab>

        <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="Tab2" KeyTip="2" />
        <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="Tab3" KeyTip="3" />
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by adding the following line of code before i show the WPF Window:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(this);
```

This is necessary if you mix WinForms and WPF windows in the same project at least if the WinForm is shown before the WPF window.

Answer (score 0):

In Ribbon cotrol add property: KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation

```
 <ribbon:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top" SelectedIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="Contained">
```

It's working for me.